# How to limit DataSnap REST to only one connection?

Tags: delphi, datasnap

I use a former Delphi library. Regrettably it is based on global variables, so multi-threading calls are not possible. It has been working fine in a desktop app.
Now, I want to expose their services in a Rest Server. I wanted to use DataSnap application. How can I limit the number of concurrent calls to only one?
The server has low load, so it would not be a problem. If another connection arrives in the middle of a previous call, the system must to put it in a pipe until previous call is finished. Is it possible?

Comment: The answer would be yes. A Critical section/Mutex is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution to your problem, based on assumptions because I can't see your actual code, would be to declare your global variables in a [ThreadVar](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=ThreadVar) section of the unit: doing so you will have an independent variable value on each thread . 
Having separate variables values will allow you to have multiple connections and to have to work with synchronization ...